# PHP and JQuery Chat

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm creating a social network type deal and I want to add a chat feature.

Currently I have a home.php that has a friends list on it, the friends list is loaded via jQuery and PHP like so:

```
function LoadList() {
    $.get("friends_feed.php",
        function (data) {
            $('div#friendsfeed').html(data);
        }
    );
}
```

For each friend that gets loaded into the list, I want to make it where when you click their name it creates a div that is fixed at the bottom of the screen, this div will be a chat box. I am hoping to be able to simply just load it in via PHP and Ajax. How to approach this?

EDIT: I only want the chat to be between the two people. The user and their friend.

Comment: Which part do you need help with? Creating the `<div>`? Using Ajax? Updating frequently? The PHP part?

Comment: Im lost actualy, I dont know if i'll simply be able to create all of the chat box in php and then just load it in? or have to add a div using jquery and load all of the data in from a php page. @minitech

Answer (score 3):

Creating a chat system as you want isn't too hard but you do have to know what your doing. You will first need a file that will initially load the chat when you click a user.

### Load Chat

```
function loadChat (userid) {
    $.get("/ajax/getChat.php", {
        userid: userid
    }, function (data) {
        //add the chat
    });
}
```

Then you will need to be able to ping the chats so that you can receive new messages. I suggest using either [web sockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets) or the easier approach, [server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events). I don't suggest polling.

### Ping Chat

Server-sent events could look like:

```
var pinger = new EventSource("/ajax/pingMessages/" + userid);
pinger.onmessage = function (data) {
    data = data.data;
    // append messages
};
```

While SSE's have less support than just polling using AJAX, they work better and allow you to keep an open connection with the server which in the end saves resource. There are a few poly fills for SSE's out there that you can check out.

You will also need a send function.

### Send Message

```
function send (userid) {
    $.post("/ajax/send.php", {
        userid: userid,
        message: $.trim($('.chat[data-id*="'+ userid +'"] input[type="text"]').val())
    });
}
```

**NOTE** All of these request only take in the `userid`. In the server-side you can take in consideration the current users id.

You should setup 1 table for the messages. Give the conversation an unique `id` and go from there. You will need to do a lot more in the server end than in the actual JavaScript.

I've created a chat before using server-sent events and AJAX. Most of the logic was in the server side.

I'm not sure if this helped but I think this might give you a little idea.

Comment: Yeah it helped a little, I'm not too good with JS and HORRIBLE with Jquery, but I'm amazing with php... So I was trying to work more in familiar grounds.

Comment: To create a chat you are going to need to have some pretty advanced knowledge in JavaScript. It's good to be great with jQuery as well as it will make your life as a developer either. Just know, there are 3 main things you need: `Load Chat`, `Ping Chat`, `Send`

Comment: Very nice Answer, +1. @Kingofslowmo, now you have a roadmap and weeks of development ahead, good luck ;) Try to read [ask] and the related articles linked in that page. Will make your Q's more productive.